# "Credit Card" input field not usable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working with the Stripe API, and following the steps that are provided in the documentation to get the bases of the API up and running on my template site.

The problem however is when I load up the web page the input field for the credit card is only being displayed as:

[image]

From everything I have researched this seems to be a common problem, and the fix seems to be putting the `width: 100%;` 
However, this isn't resolving the problem and I'm still new to credit processors and the stripe API as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <?php
        require "head.php";
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/payment.css">
    <body>
        <!--Payment form -->
        <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="card-element">
                    Credit or debit card
                    <br>
                </label>
                <div id="card-element">
                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                </div>

                <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
            </div>

            <button>Submit Payment</button>
        </form>

        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <script src="js/charge.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 .StripeElement {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  width: 100%;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;

  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}


.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
    // Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_7tbdMrboQmyUAxpjB40MQiR4008DME46WY');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “*...the credit card is only being displayed as:*” - as what?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the image, but I have made the edit and attached it above.

Comment: Use your browser's _Elements_ console to inspect the input and find out what styles or properties are setting its width

Comment: Use Safari Web Inspector or Chrome Dev Tools.
First of all - check javascript console  for Stripe-related errors. If everything ok, check `<div id="card-element">` for it's content and styles.

Comment: Alright I'll look into that once here in a little while.

Comment: Please include in your questions: What is the browser you are using and include a working code snippet if you can, that helps a lot!